# How to automatically extract images from the cache on chrome (or other browser)

Tags: images, internet, caching

I've been wondering if there is any way to automatically download images (.png mostly) while you are browsing internet. 
To be clear I'd like to grab the image at the moment they are downloaded on my cache folder. 
From the sources folders like here, I know I can do it one by one with the network tool but I'd like to do it with a lots of images.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software (and I guess you are), please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

ChromeCacheView is a small utility that reads the cache folder of Google Chrome Web browser, and displays the list of all files currently stored in the cache. For each cache file, the following information is displayed: URL, Content type, File size, Last accessed time, Expiration time, Server name, Server response, and more. 
You can easily select one or more items from the cache list, and then extract the files to another folder, or copy the URLs list to the clipboard.